# Eliminar el ultimo carácter de un string en una función de postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, funciones

Tengo un proceso en postgre, que dando el nombre de una tabla y la clave genera un insert de esas tabla y el registro indicado.

Por una parte saco los nombres de la columna y lo concateno en el campo nom_columna2

Luego saco los datos de la tabla y los concateno en el campo datos2

Por ultimo concateno los dos campos para generar la sentencia INSERT completa.

Pero tengo un problema que al ir poniendo la coma **","** en las columnas y en los datos estoy añadiendo una ultima **,**.

INSERT INTO clientes (cod_cliente, nombre, apellido **,** ) VALUES('123456', 'Juan', 'Fernandez'**,** );

He intentado con: rtrim(sentecia_INSERT,',');

Y sale el siguiente error:

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «rtrim»

¿Como podria quitar esas ultimas comas ","?

El código es el siguiente

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ops.extrae_tarjetas()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    declare 
        datos_clientes  RECORD;
        colum_clientes  RECORD;
        columna                     varchar;
        nom_columna1                    varchar;
        nom_columna2                    varchar;
        datos1                      varchar;
        datos2                      varchar;
        valor                       varchar;
        sql_select                  varchar;
        sentecia_INSERT             varchar;
        id_cliente                  varchar;
        id_tabla                    varchar;
    
        cur_datos_clientes cursor for select * from pan_token_cifrado ptc where pan = id_cliente;
        cur_colum_clientes cursor for SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'libros' AND table_name   = id_tabla;
             
    begin
         id_tabla = 'clientes'
         nom_columna2 := 'INSERT INTO ' || id_tabla || ' (';
         datos2 := ') VALUES(';
         id_cliente := '123456';
         OPEN cur_datos_clientes;
         loop   
         FETCH cur_datos_clientes INTO datos_clientes;
         EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
         
         OPEN cur_colum_clientes;
         loop
         FETCH cur_colum_clientes INTO colum_clientes;
         EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;                        
    
            nom_columna1 := colum_clientes.column_name || ', ';
            nom_columna2 := nom_columna2 || nom_columna1; 
            
            columna:= colum_clientes.column_name;
            sql_select := 'select ' || columna || ' from ' id_tabla || ' where cod_cliente = '|| '''' || id_cliente || '''';
      
            EXECUTE sql_select into valor;
       
                datos1 := '''' || valor || '''' || ', ';
                datos2 := datos2 || datos1 ;
         END LOOP;
         END LOOP;
        sentecia_INSERT := nom_columna2 || datos2 || ');';
       RAISE notice ' %', sentecia_INSERT; 
       commit;
   RETURN;
END
$procedure$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente luego de los LOOPs:

```sql
sentecia_INSERT := nom_columna2 || datos2 ;  
sentecia_INSERT := (SELECT  rtrim(sentecia_INSERT,',')); --asignar el resultado del RTRIM
sentecia_INSERT := sentecia_INSERT || ');';-- concatenar el  )
```

Comment: Da error "ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «SELECT»
  Position: 4952"

Comment: Lo encerré dentro de parentisis() , por favor intenta esa opción

Answer (score 0):

El resutlado de `RTRIM` se tiene que asignar a una variable, pues no hace nada sobre el contenido de la variable, sólo crea una nueva cadena a partir de la que le proporcionas. Si sólo estás ejecutando

```
RTRIM(sentecia_INSERT,',');
```

en una línea, te saldrá un error como el que describes. Usa una asignación del tipo

```
sentencia_INSERT := RTRIM(sentecia_INSERT,',');
```